# Nginx http redirect to https

Tags: nginx, https

I have config like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.pl *.example.pl;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.pl/$1 permanent;

}

server {
    listen 80;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/ssl/server.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    server_name www.example.pl;
    root /var/www/example/public/;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
}
```

So now every subdomain like xx234.example.pl is rewrite to http://www.example.pl

Now I try to set https. https://www.example.pl works ok, but I can't redirect traffic from http to https.
When I do this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.pl *.example.pl;
    #rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.pl/$1 permanent;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

It's redirect but to https://example.pl without www. How to redirect it correctly. I want to have that same configuration but with https.

This also doesn't work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.pl *.example.pl;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.pl/$1 permanent;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

First you switched from using `www.example.pl` to `$server_name` (which is why the `www.` disappeared).

Second, your other server block is already handling `http://www.example.pl`.

Remove the `listen 80;` from the second `server` block, so that it only handles `https` connections. Use `return 301 https://www.example.pl$request_uri;` to perform the redirect to the correct scheme and server name.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.pl *.example.pl;
    return 301 https://www.example.pl$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.pl;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) Sets names of a virtual server, for example:
>
> ```
> server {
>     server_name example.com www.example.com;
> }
> ```
>
> The first name becomes the primary server name.

Now, as you have `server_name example.pl *.example.pl;`, the `example.pl` has become your **primary server name** you are using in your

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

It's not a surprise this redirects to `example.pl` instead of `www.example.pl`. To change it, simply add `www.example.pl` in the beginning:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.pl example.pl *.example.pl;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Now you can also remove the `listen 80;` from your SSL `server{}` section as it has become unnecessary.